# How to parse time stamp and time zone offset simultaneously with Moshi?

Tags: kotlin, timezone-offset, moshi, threetenbp

A JSON-API-response contains the following properties:

```
created_at_timestamp: 1565979486,
timezone: "+01:00",
```

I am using [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) and [ThreeTenBp](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) to parse the time stamps and prepared the following custom adapters:

```
class ZonedDateTimeAdapter {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(jsonValue: Long?) = jsonValue?.let {
        try {
            ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(jsonValue), ZoneOffset.UTC) // <---
        } catch (e: DateTimeParseException) {
            println(e.message)
            null
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see the zone offset is **hardcoded** here.

```
class ZonedDateTimeJsonAdapter : JsonAdapter<ZonedDateTime>() {

    private val delegate = ZonedDateTimeAdapter()

    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): ZonedDateTime? {
        val jsonValue = reader.nextLong()
        return delegate.fromJson(jsonValue)
    }

}
```

...

```
class ZoneOffsetAdapter {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(jsonValue: String?) = jsonValue?.let {
        try {
            ZoneOffset.of(jsonValue)
        } catch (e: DateTimeException) {
            println(e.message)
            null
        }
    }

}
```

...

```
class ZoneOffsetJsonAdapter : JsonAdapter<ZoneOffset>() {

    private val delegate = ZoneOffsetAdapter()

    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): ZoneOffset? {
        val jsonValue = reader.nextString()
        return delegate.fromJson(jsonValue)
    }

}
```

The adapters are registered with `Moshi` as follows:

```
Moshi.Builder()
    .add(ZoneOffset::class.java, ZoneOffsetJsonAdapter())
    .add(ZonedDateTime::class.java, ZonedDateTimeJsonAdapter())
    .build()
```

Parsing the individual fields (`created_at_timestamp`, `timezone`) works fine. I want however **get rid** of the **hardcoded** zone offset. How can I configure Moshi to fall back on the `timezone` property when parsing the `created_at_timestamp` property.

## Related

- [Advanced JSON parsing techniques using Moshi and Kotlin](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/advanced-json-parsing-techniques-using-moshi-and-kotlin-daf56a7b963d)
- [The work-in-progress branch of the related project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/engelsystem/tree/time-zone-offset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `created_at_timestamp` field you should use a type that doesn't have a timezone. This is usually `Instant`. It identifies a moment in time independent of which timezone it is being interpreted in.

Then in your enclosing type you can define a getter method to combine the instant and zone into one value. The `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant` method can do this.

Comment: Thank you! That was the perfect hint. I changed the implementation according to your recommendation, tested it and updated the branch.